# Replace a string under condition (Regex?)

Tags: php, regex, replace

I am looking for a solution for search and replace. 
I would need to add an empty space after specific string **BUT only if there isn't one already.** Regular expressions are to advanced for me.  Anyone wants to help me out?

For example

```
Lorem ipsum[something]abcdefg[/something]dolor sit amet
```

Needs to be replace with

```
Lorem ipsum[something]abcdefg[/something] dolor sit amet
```

So, I need to search for `[/something]` and if it is not followed by space, then do the replace...

Comment: What's the language?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know Regex is tied to language, it is PHP or executing mySql statement

Comment: MySQL statement sure not. I will remove that tag.

Comment: Regex is not tied to language, but the way you replace all occurrences is. In Java, you'd write something like `s.replaceAll("yourregex", "new value")`. In javascript would be something like `s.replace(/yourregex/g, RegExp.$1...)`

Comment: @BorisKozarac my answer solves your problem, for sure. Try it and tell us :)

Comment: yes, thank you very much, I will explore further :)

Comment: You are welcome. Tell us if you have problems with this. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression can be this:

```
/(\[\/something\])(?!\s)/gmi
```

You can test it and know the whole explanation here:

https://regex101.com/r/pC4pQ3/1

If you see the first is targetted because is not an space, but the second is the opposite.

To apply this in PHP you must to use <kbd>[`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)</kbd>. Something like this:

```
$string = "Lorem ipsum[something]abcdefg[/something]dolor sit amet";
echo preg_replace("/(\[\/something\])(?!\s)/", "\1 ", $string);
// result: "Lorem ipsum[something]abcdefg[/something] dolor sit amet"
```